# Почему в "собранный" две Н

Tags: морфология

Почему в прилагательном *собра**нн**ый* две буквы Н? Есть правило, что суффиксы *ан*/*ян* пишутся с одной **н**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Суффиксы -ан - -ян пишутся в прилагательных, образованных от существительных (глиняный от глина, кожаный от кожа). Причастие "собранный" образовано от глагола совершенного вида "собрать". В таком случае, согласно общеизвестному правилу, пишется -НН-